# Pass Arraylist in post request to neo4j

Tags: rest, plugins, neo4j

I want to pass an array list to post request to Neo4j server, instead I get an warning at startup when I try run `systemctl status neo4j`.

> WARN  Failed to load plugin [ServerPlugin[KShortestPaths]]:
>   Unsupported parameter type: java.util.ArrayList

I want to pass something like:

```
{
    "concept1":"C0000039",
    "vocabulary": ["MSH", "NDFRT"]
}
```

Comment: Neo4j supports multiple props values:
`CREATE (:myNode {concept:'C0000039', vocabulary:["MSH","NDFRT"]})`
So the error is related to something different: wrong labels for node props, wrong syntax for the POST requests. 
Can you post some more code regarding your application?

Comment: I tried the following in the browser and it works, so there must be something wrong in what you pass to the server  

:param record : {
    "concept1":"C0000039",
    "vocabulary": ["MSH", "NDFRT"]
}

RETURN $record.concept1,$record.vocabulary[0];

Comment: The error looks like it is coming from a Neo4j Plugin. Did you write a Neo4j plugin? Can you share the code for your plugin?